# How to output image, video and audio players in a new window

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have three table rows which contains a list of Images, Videos and Audio in their respective rows:

```
    echo '<td width="11%" class="imagetd">'. ( ( empty ($arrImageFile[$key]) ) ? "&nbsp;" : '<ul class="qandaul"><li>'.htmlspecialchars( is_array( $arrImageFile[$key] ) ? implode(",", $arrImageFile[$key]) : $arrImageFile[$key] ) ). '</li></ul></td>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<td width="11%" class="videotd">'. ( ( empty ($arrVideoFile[$key]) ) ? "&nbsp;" : '<ul class="qandaul"><li>'.htmlspecialchars( is_array( $arrVideoFile[$key] ) ? implode(",", $arrVideoFile[$key]) : $arrVideoFile[$key] ) ). '</li></ul></td>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<td width="11%" class="audiotd">'. ( ( empty ($arrAudioFile[$key]) ) ? "&nbsp;" : '<ul class="qandaul"><li>'.htmlspecialchars( is_array( $arrAudioFile[$key] ) ? implode(",", $arrAudioFile[$key]) : $arrAudioFile[$key] ) ). '</li></ul></td>' . PHP_EOL;
```

The list is an array which contains data coming from the database. Below is the code for the video array and database. The audio and image has a similar set up

```
    $vidquery = "SELECT s.SessionId, q.QuestionId, v.VideoId, VideoFile
                FROM Session s
                INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
                INNER JOIN Video_Question vq ON q.QuestionId = vq.QuestionId
                INNER JOIN Video v ON vq.VideoId = v.VideoId
                WHERE s.SessionId = ?";

    global $mysqli;
    $vidqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($vidquery);
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $vidqrystmt->bind_param("i",$_POST["session"]);
    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
    $vidqrystmt->execute(); 
    $vidqrystmt->bind_result($vidSessionId,$vidQuestionId,$vidVideoId,$vidVideoFile);

        $arrVideoFile = array();

    while ($vidqrystmt->fetch()) {
    $arrVideoFile[] = basename($vidVideoFile);
  }

    $vidqrystmt->close();
```

Now at the moment it just lists the image, video and audio file names in a bullet point list. But what I want to do is that I want to set each file as a hyperlink so that if the user clicks on either of the links, it will display the image, video or audio in a separate page (a separate window will open up), either as a larger or displaying a player to play the video or audio.

My question is how can this be done, what are the following steps I need to do?

Comment: If you do not understand question or you feel question needs to improve, please comment to me. Please comment to me if you are working on a solution so I know what's going on. Thanks

Comment: [Please **quit** this thing of making new question out of totally different one in order to cheat on bounty timeout!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14305295/285587)

Comment: Why can't I, the other question had no answers so instead of creating new questions I just replace an old one and set up a bounty as this is not an simple question and I want to reward extra points to people who help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
//start:procedure
$img_result = '';
if(empty($arrImageFile[$key])){
  $img_result = '&nbsp;';
}else{
  $img_$result .=  '<ul class="qandaul"><li>';
   if(is_array( $arrImageFile[$key] )){
    foreach($arrImageFile[$key] as $filename){
     $img_$result.= CreateLink($filename, "image");
    }
   }else{
    $img_$result.= CreateLink($arrImageFile[$key], "image");
   }
   $img_result.= '</li></ul>';
}
//end:procedure

echo '<td width="11%" class="imagetd">'.$img_result.'</td>' . PHP_EOL;


function CreateLink($filename, $type){
 if($type == 'image'){
  return '<a href="imageviewer.php?filename='.$filename.'" title="Click to view in New window" target="_blank">'.htmlspecialchars($filename).'</a>';
 }
 if($type == 'video'){

 }
 if($type == 'audio'){

 }
}
?>
```

You can also create a general function for all of them using structured approach (starting from starting procedure above to the end)

```
<?php
echo '<td width="11%" class="imagetd">'.customfunction($arrImageFile[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
//same idea for other td also
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to wrap every media element (audio, image, video) into a tag - anchor (a) for example like this:

```
<a href='previewImage.php?imgId=[xxx]' target='_blank'>myImage.jpg</a>
```

Where [xxx] is the id of the image or it's name.

In the `previewImage.php` you get it with `$_GET['imgId']` , select it from DB and display it. Similar for `previewVideo.php` and `previewAudio.php`

Comment: I dont know who down voted it. I will give it a try tho, I will get back to you on the outcome

Comment: Thank you... If you need help implementing this solution you can comment here - I might help you!

Comment: I will be testing your answer now, I will let you know in a bit the outcome

Comment: Ok! Good luck with that ! :)

Comment: IMHO opening in new window is somewhat antique these days;) However this solution should work fine.

Comment: @GabrielLupu Im gonna have to ask a big favour from you. Just for image can you write out fully how the code should be written? I know I am asking a lot but the hyperlinks is giving me erros and been trying for hours to fix it but cant. Show us the full code for how to do it all for image and I will apply it for video and audio (I will create the players myself). Thanks. I will definitly give you bounty, best answer and upvote if you can do this for me

Comment: I will give it a try - I will message you !

Comment: Ok cheers, just been struggling because keep getting errors when trying to create the hyperlinks

Comment: If you have a list of images in the db, you should separate them using explode (http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) then iterate trought the result to generate hiperlinks!